# Improving mongo aggregation to build bipartite graph

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've two collections containing employees and projects. Each project has an array of tags and each employee has an array of preferences, where each preference is an object with tag and score attributes (employee preferences have a score based on the order they have chosen them).

Example of employees:

```
[{
    "name":"employee1",
    "preferences":[
        {
            "tag": "tag1",
            "score": 3
        },
        {
            "tag": "tag2",
            "score": 2
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name":"employee2",
    "preferences":[
        {
            "tag": "tag2",
            "score": 3
        },
        {
            "tag": "tag3",
            "score": 2
        }
    ]
}]
```

Example of projects:

```
[{
    "name":"project1",
    "tags":["tag1", "tag2"]
},
{
    "name":"project2",
    "tags":["tag2", "tag3"]
}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{
    "project": "project1",
    "employee": "employee1",
    "score": 5
},
{
    "project": "project2",
    "employee": "employee1",
    "score": 2
},
{
    "project": "project1",
    "employee": "employee2",
    "score": 2
},
{
    "project": "project2",
    "employee": "employee2",
    "score": 5
}]
```

I wrote this aggregation pipeline, which give me the desired output (not exactly the same, but is just matter of adding a projection stage):

```
db.employees.aggregate([
  {
    '$unwind' : '$preferences'
  },
  {
    '$lookup' : {
      'from' : 'projects',
      'localField' : 'preferences.tag',
      'foreignField': 'tags',
      'as' : 'match'
    }
  },
  {
    '$group' :
      {
        '_id': {'project' : '$match.name', 'employee' : '$name' },
        'score' : { '$sum' : '$preferences.score' }
      }
  },
  {
    '$unwind': '$_id.project'
  },
  {
    '$group' :
      {
        '_id': {'project' : '$_id.project', 'employee' : '$_id.employee' },
        'score' : { '$sum' : '$score' }
      }
  }
])
```

Now this is a working solution, but I'm not sure it is the best one. I'm doing some tests with a variable number of documents, from 100 to 5000 for each collection, and I'm comparing it with a simple iterative approach using nested for cycles, and the result is that the iterative approach is actually faster and lighter (executes in less time, using less memory).
I thought that the aggregation would became better increasing the number of documents but it seems not. Do you have any suggestion to improve the pipe? Any ideas in general? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: make sure, that your `$lookup` target `foreignField` is indexed. Then, start with describing your data-specific characteristic: is it common for one user to have a lot of preferences? Or for a project to have a lot of tags? Disproportion in sizes of `employees` and `projects` will also affect performance.

Now, let's get to experiments.

1. Baseline (your solution). Remember to index `projects.tags`!

```js
db.employees.aggregate([
  {$unwind: '$preferences'},
  {$lookup: {
    from: 'projects',
    localField: 'preferences.tag',
    foreignField: 'tags',
    as: 'match'
  }},
  {$group: {
    _id: {project: '$match.name', employee: '$name'},
    score: {$sum: '$preferences.score'}
  }},
  {$unwind: '$_id.project'},
  {$group: {
    _id: {project: '$_id.project', employee: '$_id.employee'},
    score: {$sum: '$score'}
  }}
])
```

2. Getting rid of one `$group` stage. Remember to index `projects.tags`!

```js
db.employees.aggregate([
  {$unwind: '$preferences'},
  {$lookup: {
    from: 'projects',
    localField: 'preferences.tag',
    foreignField: 'tags',
    as: 'match'
  }},
  {$unwind: '$match'},
  {$group: {
    _id: {project: '$match.name', employee: '$name'},
    score: {$sum: '$preferences.score'}
  }}
])
```

3. Getting rid of **both** `$group` stages. This will work **only** if `employees.preferences.tag` will be unique (it'll count duplicates multiple times). Remember to index `projects.tags`!

```js
db.employees.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
    from: 'projects',
    localField: 'preferences.tag',
    foreignField: 'tags',
    as: 'match'}},
  {$unwind: '$match'},
  {$project: {
    _id: 0,
    employee: '$name',
    project: '$match.name',
    score: {$reduce: {
      input: '$preferences',
      initialValue: 0,
      in: {$cond: [
        {$in: ['$$this.tag', '$match.tags']},
        {$add: ['$$this.score', '$$value']},
        '$$value'
      ]}
    }}
  }}
])
```

4. Just like 3, but in reverse direction. This will work **only** if `employees.preferences.tag` will be unique (it'll count duplicates multiple times). Remember to index `employees.preferences.tag`!

```js
db.projects.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
    from: 'employees',
    localField: 'tags',
    foreignField: 'preferences.tag',
    as: 'match'
  }},
  {$unwind: '$match'},
  {$project: {
    _id: 0,
    employee: '$match.name',
    project: '$name',
    score: {$reduce: {
      input: '$match.preferences',
      initialValue: 0,
      in: {$cond: [
        {$in: ['$$this.tag', '$tags']},
        {$add: ['$$this.score', '$$value']},
        '$$value'
      ]}
    }}
  }}
])
```

And results. Tested on MongoDB, version 4.0.10. I've prepared a DB with `n` emploees and projects, 1-7 preferences/tags each.

```
n | 10     | 100    | 1000   |
--|--------|--------|--------|
1 | 0.004s | 0.070s | 4.061s |
2 | 0.004s | 0.069s | 4.022s |
3 | 0.002s | 0.051s | 3.983s |
4 | 0.002s | 0.060s | 4.225s |
```

And, if we disrupt the sizes, to have 10x more employees than projects (`n`)...

```
n | 10     | 100    | 500    |
--|--------|--------|--------|
1 | 0.038s | 0.674s | 19.42s |
2 | 0.036s | 0.672s | 17.91s |
3 | 0.017s | 0.482s | 10.42s |
4 | 0.018s | 0.497s | 12.13s |
```

And, if we disrupt the sizes, to have 10x more projects than employees (`n`)...

```
n | 10     | 100    | 500    |
--|--------|--------|--------|
1 | 0.014s | 0.466s | 16.22s |
2 | 0.015s | 0.481s | 16.08s |
3 | 0.012s | 0.476s | 10.30s |
4 | 0.032s | 0.697s | 13.09s |
```

As you can see, it all depends. Benchmark all of these on your data and pick the best solution.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, it is really helpful. In my scenario I'm assuming that there is an equal number of employee and projects, that each employee select roughly the same number of tags and each project has the same. I have just one more question: how did you indexed employee.preferences.tag? Just using: db.projects.createIndex({'tags' : 1})? And sorry but this question may sound stupid: should I invoke this function each time I make a new insertion on the collection?

Comment: Simply by doing `db.employees.createIndex({'preferences.tag': 1})` ([`createIndex` docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/)) - it will create a [multikey index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#multikey-index). No, you don't have to run it every time. If you are not familiar with indexing, read more in these two pages I've linked.

Comment: I'm testing now your solutions and it seems that the the one with the reduce function is actually lightning if compared to others (executes in less than 0.01 seconds even on 10'000 employees and 10'000 projects). This makes me think that I somehow misunderstood your warning on `employees.preferences.tag` uniqueness. Can you please explain me better what you mean?

Comment: If these values won't be unique it _may_ return invalid results, as it's counting each preference times each project. If someone will have `[{tag: 1, score: 1}, {tag: 1, score: 1}]` it'll be the same as `[{tag: 1, score: 2}]`.